# I have code that calls the most recent file in my folder how can I call that file in a Vlookup function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hello I using a function that calls out the most recent file in my folder. I need to automate a vlookup for the file. I'm having problems properly calling the file out

I already tried calling it by its path but I believe I didn't call it correctly .

```
Sub oversub()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\TAmon1\Desktop\OverSubscription Dash"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
Dim wb As Workbook
'wbstring = MyPath & LatestFile
Windows("Planning_tool.xlsm").Activate

Range("N2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(C[-13],'Router_level_crosstab.csv'!C1:C11,11,FALSE)"
    Range("N2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N539")
    Range("N2:N539").Select
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("O2").Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("O2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(C[-14],'Router_level_crosstab.csv'!C1:C11,5,FALSE)"
    Range("O2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O2:O539")
    Range("O2:O539").Select
    Range("Q2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(C[-16],'Router_level_crosstab.csv'!C1:C11,9,FALSE)"
    Range("Q2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2:Q539")
    Range("Q2:Q539").Select
```

Currently I am calling the direct file which does work but when I have the a new file I would need to manually change the file name. I need to incorporate the latest file in the Vlookup.

Comment: You need to set that file to a variable while opening, so change `Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile` this to `Set Lat_book = Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile` then you can use object `Lat_book` anywhere in your code to identify the latest workbook

Comment: Using Set Lat_book = Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile gives me a error on the line its saying there is a end of statement on Mypath